# Subset Sum Search Problem for Input with At Most One Solution

Tags: algorithms, np-complete, polynomial-time, subset-sum

**Edit:** This question has been reasked [on TCS](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/42502/subset-sum-problem-with-at-most-one-solution-for-any-target).

---

We first consider the search version of the subset sum problem: Given a set $S$ of $n$ naturals, find a subset of $S$ that sums to exactly $W$. My question concerns this problem, with an additional restriction on set $S$: For all possible values of $X$, there exists at most one subset that sums to $X$ (in other words, no two subsets of $S$ sum to the same value). Can we find a polynomial time algorithm for this problem given this restriction?

---

My thoughts: The reason I think this may be possible is because this is an **extremely** strong restriction on $S$. Most sets are very far from having this property. The construction of an algorithm would likely begin with a strong characterization of the sets that even have this property, and work from there. However, I'm having trouble proving strong theorems about the sets that obey this restriction.

Comment: Problems with such guarantees are known as [promise problems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Promise_problem). Sometimes these promises don't help (for example, it's hard to find a Hamiltonian cycle even if we know it exists) but sometimes they do (for example, you can find a satisfying assignment for $n$-variable SAT if the formula has at least $2^n/n$ satisfying assignments).

Comment: @Juho I see. Do you think that this problem is solvable?

Comment: No, I think it's hard in the following sense. UNIQUE-SAT is SAT with a unique solution, and the problem is $D^P$-complete (yes, see [here](https://cs.stackexchange.com/a/13888/472)). Now, I guess all you need is a parsimonious reduction from SAT to SUBSET SUM and you are done. I think this is just a matter of putting the pieces together carefully.

Comment: If you take $n$ random integers, each $n^2$ bits long, then it will satisfy your restriction.  I don't know whether the subset sum problem is expected to be hard on that distribution.

Comment: @Juho, I think that argument would work if the promise was that there is a unique solution (there is a unique subset that sums to the target).  But here we have a stronger promise regarding the set $S$: for all other possible targets, it's also true that there is at most one subset that sums to them.  I don't see how to make the UNIQUE-SAT ideas apply given this stronger promise.

Comment: @D.W. You are right. Perhaps it's worthwhile to still leave my comment around at least for some time.

Comment: This seems a research-level question. I suggest asking it on [TCS](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: @xskxzr [done](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/42502/subset-sum-problem-with-at-most-one-solution-for-any-target)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question because it was cross-posted on CS.SE.

Comment: @xskxzr, may I make a request for the future?  When suggesting another site, it would be great if you could let the poster know not to cross-post.  You can suggest they flag the post for migration, or that they delete this copy before posting elsewhere.  Hopefully that will provide a better experience for all.  Thank you for considering it!

Comment: @D.W. my bad, I did not know that this was standard policy. I'll do this in the future

Comment: @D.W. My bad, I'll keep it in mind.